# Get exception when add to database in Linq-to-SQL

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, winforms, linq-to-sql

My database is in SQL Server and I use Linq-to-SQL. I used from SP(Save cards) .
I put breakpoint in my code, when arrive at `rdr = cmm.ExecuteReader();` get me exception!!!

```
 private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
            PersianCalendar jc = new PersianCalendar();
            string SaveDate = jc.GetYear(DateTime.Now).ToString();
            int from=Convert.ToInt32(txt_barcode_f.Text);
            int to=Convert.ToInt32(txt_barcode_t .Text);
            int quantity=Convert.ToInt32(to-from);
            int card_Type_ID=Convert.ToInt32(cmb_BracodeType .SelectedValue);
            int[] arrCardNum = new int[quantity];

            arrCardNum[0]=from;

             for (int i = from; i < to;i++ )
             {
                 for(int j=0; j<quantity ;j++)
                 {
                 arrCardNum[j]=from+j;
                 int r = arrCardNum[j];
                 sp.SaveCards(r, 2, card_Type_ID, SaveDate, 2);
                 }
             }
        }  

public void SaveCards(int Barcode_Num, int Card_Status_ID, int Card_Type_ID, string Save_Date, int Save_User_ID)
        {

                IDbCommand cmm;
                cmm = Linq.Connection.CreateCommand();
                try
                {           
                    cmm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Barcode_Num", Barcode_Num));
                    cmm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Card_Status_ID", 2));
                    cmm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Card_Type_ID", Card_Type_ID));
                    cmm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@SaveDate", Save_Date));
                    cmm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Save_User_ID", Save_User_ID));
                    cmm.CommandText = "SaveCards";
                    cmm.Connection.Open();
                    cmm.Connection = Linq.Connection;
                    cmm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    IDataReader rdr = null;

                    **rdr = cmm.ExecuteReader();**
                    while (rdr.Read())
                    {
                        Console.Write(" All Insert ! " + "\n");
                    }
                }
                catch (SqlException ex)
                {
                    SqlExceptionHandler(ex, Save_User_ID);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    PopularEexceptionHandler(ex, Save_User_ID);
                }
                finally
                { cmm.Connection.Close(); }

        }
```

when excute sp, show no result and display this:

```
when execute sp , display this:The INSERT statement conflicted with the CHECK constraint "CK_BarCode_Num". The conflict occurred in database "Parking", table "dbo.TBL_Cards", column 'BarCode_Num'. The statement has been terminated. No rows affected. (0 row(s) returned) @RETURN_VALUE = -6
```

Comment: give me exception yet!!! it is :"SqL Exception was caugth"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're a bit chaotic on how you set up your connection and command..... e.g. you **open** the connection **before** you even assign it! How is that going to work??

My recommendation would be this order (based on the principle *first do all the setup **before** opening the connection*, and furthermore *open the connection as late as possible, close it as quickly as possible*) :

```
IDbCommand cmm = Linq.Connection.CreateCommand();

try
{           
   // define name and type of command
   cmm.CommandText = "SaveCards";
   cmm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

   // assign connection
   cmm.Connection = Linq.Connection;

   // define parameters
   cmm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Barcode_Num", Barcode_Num));
   cmm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Card_Status_ID", 2));
   cmm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Card_Type_ID", Card_Type_ID));
   cmm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@SaveDate", Save_Date));
   cmm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Save_User_ID", Save_User_ID));

   // only now - after all the setup - open the connection, read the data
   cmm.Connection.Open();

   IDataReader rdr = rdr = cmm.ExecuteReader();

   while (rdr.Read())
   {
      ....
   }
}
```

To catch the errors that the execution throws, replace your `catch` block for the `SqlException` with this:

```
catch (SqlException ex)
{
   StringBuilder sbErrors = new StringBuilder();

   foreach (SqlError error in ex.Errors)
   {
      sbErrors.AppendLine(error.Message);
   }

   string allErrors = sbErrors.ToString();
}
```

and debug into that catch block - what is the `allErrors` string in the end??

**Update:** after a chat session, we know finally know what the message in the SQL exception is:

> *The INSERT statement conflicted with the CHECK constraint "CK_BarCode_Num". The conflict occurred in database "Parking", table "dbo.TBL_Cards", column 'BarCode_Num'.*

Now we're trying to find out what that constraint is / does and why it gets violated....

Comment: go to: catch (SqlException ex)
                {
                    SqlExceptionHandler(ex, Save_User_ID);
                }

Comment: in line:"IDataReader rdr = rdr = cmm.ExecuteReader();" give exception

Comment: what do i say for solving my problem?

Comment: maybe the problem is the store procedure?

Comment: ok.in view detail exception:Data:{System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal}---Errors:{System.Data.SqlClient.SqlErrorCollection}------Source:.Net SqlClient Data Provider

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19680/discussion-between-user1770370-and-marc-s)

Comment: output : Name:CK_BarCode_Num ,definition:(datalength([BarCode_Num])=(13))

Comment: when execute sp , display this:The INSERT statement conflicted with the CHECK constraint "CK_BarCode_Num". The conflict occurred in database "Parking", table "dbo.TBL_Cards", column 'BarCode_Num'.
The statement has been terminated.
No rows affected.
(0 row(s) returned)
@RETURN_VALUE = -6

Comment: @user1770370: OK - so is the value you're inserting for `@Barcode_Num` really 13 digits/characters long?? If not --> then you're violating that check constraint and your stored procedure will fail.

Answer (score 0):

I think it could be that you have `open the connection and assigning another connection` before executing the reader.

```
cmm.CommandText = "SaveCards";
//cmm.Connection.Open(); You should open the connection after assigning it
cmm.Connection = Linq.Connection;
cmm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmm.Connection.Open(); //Open it here

SqlDataReader rdr = cmm.ExecuteReader();
```

Comment: in line:"IDataReader rdr = rdr = cmm.ExecuteReader();" give exception

Comment: when execute sp , display this:The INSERT statement conflicted with the CHECK constraint "CK_BarCode_Num". The conflict occurred in database "Parking", table "dbo.TBL_Cards", column 'BarCode_Num'. The statement has been terminated. No rows affected. (0 row(s) returned) @RETURN_VALUE = -6